# Angular - How to test if child component have received the right properties?

Tags: angular, jasmine

With this html:

```
<app-parent>
    <app-child name="john" age="12"></app-child> 
</app-parent>
```

I want to create a test to validate if *app-parent* have informed properly name and age to *app-child*.
app-child will be a mocked component.

What is the right way of doing it?

I know for example that I can use:

```
const parent = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-parent'));
parent.componentInstance // { name, age }
```

But it does not look the best way.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#test-it - that would be like e2e testing, right

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it is something like this:

```
<app-parent>
  <app-child [name]="name" [age]="age"></app-child>
</app-parent>
```

I would just make sure that `component.name` and `component.age` have the accurate values and not test that the child component receives the correct values because Angular has already tested parent to child component binding. We should only test our code and not Angular's implementation/code.

Comment: Exactly. I am not trying to test angular but to test if I have informed the properties properly. Using the approach that I've told works, but it doesn't look like the best way